# EF Core 1.0 - Include() generates more than one queries

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF 7.0.0-rc1-final.

The following statement generates multiple queries on the server.
Is this normal or I am missing something ?

```
Group myGroup = dbContext_
            .Set<Group>()
            .Include(x => x.GroupRoles)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Approver");
```

I see two separate queries executed on the server:

[image: Query 1]

And

[image: Query 2]

It's a standard many-to-many scenario. Why is the first query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it’s normal even in one to many scenarios.

EF7 generates multiple queries to avoid returning the same data multiple times.

Here is a great post about EF6 Include to understand why this change was required for EF7: [Entity Framework pitfalls, include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724196/entity-framework-code-is-slow-when-using-include-many-times/34732579#34732579)