# How can I generate this query with Entity Framework to return the corresponding collections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I generate this query with Entity Framework to return the corresponding collections that the question has only one theme.

```
select * 
from TD_ENCUESTAS as e 
join td_preguntas as p on e.ENC_ID = p.PRE_ENC_ID 
join TC_TEMAS as t on p.PRE_TEM_ID = t.TEM_ID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that the models are correctly set-up, that would be quite easy:

```
var encuestas = context.Encuestas
    .Include(x => x.Preguntas.Tema)
```

For this to work, you would need:

```
public class Encuesta
{
    public virtual ICollection<Pregunta> Preguntas { get; set; }
}

public class Pregunta
{
    public Tema Tema { get; set; }
}

public class Tema
{
    // not actually needed but for clarification
    public virtual ICollection<Pregunta> Preguntas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'ICollection <td_preguntas>' does not contain a definition for 'tc_temas' nor is there any extension method 'tc_temas' that accepts a first argument of type 'ICollection <td_preguntas>' (are there any directive using or an assembly reference ?)

Comment: @DanielCruzPablo I used generic names, you should change the code to match the classes you have

Comment: Yes, I already change to generic names but I mark the same error.

Comment: Agree, this is the way EF was intended to be used. I only use joins when nav properties are not available.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
    var user = (from e in db.TD_ENCUESTAS
                join p in db.td_preguntas on e.ENC_ID equals p.PRE_ENC_ID
                join t in db.TC_TEMAS on p.PRE_TEM_ID equals t.TEM_ID;
                select new
                {
                   Name = e.ENC_DESCRIPCION,
                   Address = p.PRE_ACTIVO,
                   .....//So on...//
                });
}
```

Comment: Why would you use joins when you have the beauty of Navigation Properties for this case?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes you are right. I use join to so that he could understand  LINQ  join (as he asked in question). But of course your solution  is best one for this purpose.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Neither approach is better than the other, and each is a different result.  Using .Include generates an object graph the same as the entity classes, while using join allows you to perform a *projection* into a flattened model or a model that's organized differently than the source classes.  You should be familiar with both approaches.  Ziaul's approach can also perform better because it doesn't require a query batch as .Include does(multiple queries are batched to grab related lists), and also allows you to restrict the amount of data retrieved.

Comment: @AaronLS I'm familiar with both approaches, but I'd mostly only use the approach on this answer for flattening or projecting to different entities, and the OP didn't say they wanted that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Actually this answer is closer to the op's example SQL.   Your answer generates an object graph and also a query batch.  This answer will generate a single query with joins and provide the same access flattened view that the OP's query would.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Anyhow, your question "Why would you use joins when you have the beauty of Navigation Properties for this case?" implied that one approach is superior to the other, and that is simply not true.  They accomplish different things and each has its purpose.

Comment: @AaronLS That's not been my experience. You can easily project with navigation properties and the generated query is virtually identical.

Comment: `var test= context.Foo.Select(e => new { FooName = e.Name, BarName = e.Bar.Name }).ToList();` would generate a single query with a join. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AaronLS I've used SQL Profiler heavily and I have not seen such huge differences in how the queries are composed. I didn't mean they are superior, but they look much cleaner. They return different objects only if you want them to, this answer could return the exact same objects Include does

Comment: You can also add `Database.Log = s => Debug.Writeline(s);` into your context constructor to see the generated SQL.

Comment: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/join-in-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-considered-messy-redundant-38525

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You've misread your profiler if you think .Include generates the same query as .Join: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35536605/84206

Comment: You have a better reference than RC1 from 18 months ago? Not using EF Core here, but with EF6 this is not an issue. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: @AaronLS "in order to avoid retrieving the same data multiple times"... I don't see an issue there, even when it was a RC1

Comment: @SteveGreene That example in the article is a projection Steve, not `.Include`, and is semantically equivalent to a join with a select projection.  It generates a flattened projection, not an object graph.  Try again with .Include and you'll see the difference, EF6 or Core.