# How to retrieve child data, via LINQ Include, in one query, to improve performance?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET 4.5, MVC5, C#, LINQ, EF6, SQL Server 2012/SQL Azure.

I need to significantly improve the efficiency of a complex query. In essence the purpose of the task is to copy a "sample" recordset with many child records. I am currently doing this via C# and LINQ. I suspect that I am requerying the database within multiple Foreach blocks, thus I am causing many calls to the database. While each query is small, the number of calls is not. It could be a 200+. I believe they call this is "N+1" problem.

The following layout gives an idea of the relationships and hence queries.

```
Table1-<Table1.1
      -<Table1.2-<Table1.2.1
                -<Table1.2.2-<Table1.2.2.1
                            -<Table1.2.2.2
```

Instead of using "Foreach" to bring back "Table1.1" etc, I want to bring back all related data in one hit to minimise the number of calls to the DB. I understand I need to use "Include". I have got as far as:

```
db.Table1.Where(r=>r.Id=myId).Include(x=>x.Table1.2).Include(x=>x.Table1.2)
```

However I am not sure how to alter this statement to bring back data down to "Table1.2.2.2". This is my question.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1

I found an initial answer.

```
db.Table1.Include(x=>x.Table1.1) 
         .Include(x=>x.Table1.2) 
         .Include(x=>x.Table1.2.Select(y=>y.Table1.2.1)
```

However I may not need the middle line, so the following may be fine.

```
db.Table1.Include(x=>x.Table1.1) 
         .Include(x=>x.Table1.2.Select(y=>y.Table1.2.1)
```

Thoughts...

EDIT2

I also need to go to 5 levels down. I am finding that this one retrieve times out !! Whether this is because EF is confused on the compilation, or that the retrieve is too complicated or both I am unsure. There is possibly a limit on how many levels one can use "Include" ? Also I am unsure that by specifying the path to the grandchildren then the parent are automatically retrieved, or do you have to specify the parents separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is possibly a limit on how many levels one can use "Include"?

There is! As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732579/861716) about the generated SQL statement -

- Number of *columns* in the `SELECT` clause is the sum of all columns in all involved tables
- The number of *rows* is the sum of records in included child collections

That's potentially a *huge* (long *and* wide) result set returned from the database. Apart from that, it's hard for the db engine's query optimizer to find a good query plan. The database will have a hard time crunching all the data and it's not surprising that the command times out.

#### The alternative

The alternative is to load data in chunks. But that's easier said than done. In a way, you already load data in chunks, but these chunks are too small and the queries too many (yes, N + 1). The chunks should be larger. There's no clear-cut strategy how to do that. It depends on your table structure and the numbers of data. But let me try to point you in the right direction.

> 5 levels down

For brevity's sake, let's say the tables and associations are `A` < `B` < `C` < `D` < `E` ("<" meaning 1:n). The root query is something like

```
var query = As.Where(a => a.Property == value).ToList();
```

[So you don't want *all* `As`, because that would be easy: then you may as well load all children too.]

Let's suppose you can `Include` the `Bs` without any problems, but that including the `Cs` already gets too much. So the query becomes:

```
var query = As.Where(a => a.Property == value)
              .Include(a => a.Bs).ToList();
```

And the `Cs`, etc. should be loaded in a chunks of data.

A nice feature of Entity Framework is that it auto-connects all entities that are loaded into a context, by a process that's known as *relationship fixup*. So if you load the `Cs` separately, the collections in their parent `B` objects will be populated. That makes it easy to load the required `Cs`:

```
var cs = Cs.Where(c => c.B.A.Property == value).ToList();
```

(supposing that the back-references are also part of your model)

No if you can safely include the `Ds`, we're almost done:

```
var cs = Cs.Where(c => c.B.A.Property == value)
           .Include(c => c.Ds).ToList();
```

And the last level is loaded by:

```
var es = Es.Where(e => e.D.C.B.A.Property == value).ToList();
```

This level of nesting (the dots) may look scary. It will create a query with four joins. However, the great difference with 4 `Incudes` is that now only `E` columns and rows are queried. The query result doesn't explode. And database engines are optimized for executing joins.

So this gives you some handles to play with `Include` levels and separate queries until you have a configuration that works well (enough).

One last thing: remember to turn off lazy loading. EF does auto-populate the collections alright, but it doesn't mark them as loaded. If lazy loading is enabled, accessing the collections will still trigger N + 1 queries.

Comment: This is a stunning reply. Thank you. Most informative.